# Why are Observable operations called once (duplicated) for every subscriber?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Each time I call `.subscribe()` on an Observable, the processing on each value is restarted (in the example below, the map function will be called twice for each value).

```
var rx = require('rx-lite');
var _ = require('lodash');

var obs = rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 2]);

var processing = obs.map(function (number) {
  // This function is called twice
  console.log('call for ' + number);
  return number + 1;
});

processing.subscribe(_.noop, _.noop);
processing.subscribe(_.noop, _.noop);
```

Is there any way to have subscribe give you the processed value without rerunning the whole processing functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi @Simon Boudrias You should know about [Cold vs. Hot Observables](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html#cold-vs-hot-observables).

> Cold observables start running upon subscription, i.e., the observable sequence only starts pushing values to the observers when Subscribe is called. *Values are also not shared among subscribers* ..

In your case you can use `publish` with `connect` or `refCount`

```
var rx = require('rx-lite');
var _ = require('lodash');

var obs = rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 2]);

var processing = obs.map(function (number) {
  // This function is called twice
  console.log('call for ' + number);
  return number + 1;
}).publish();

processing.subscribe(_.noop, _.noop);
processing.subscribe(_.noop, _.noop);

processing.connect();
```